# Exclude Range of Numbers from a given Range (Port Range)

Tags: perl

I am trying to make the port range of 1-65535 allow the user to exclude certain ranges of ports from it

The input will be a comma separated single or range of port numbers, such as:
`1-2,3-4,4-5,5-6,7-8,9-10,1-100`

The output should be:
`101-65535`

I have written code to cover many cases, but for some reason the code I currently have doesn't handle the last exclusion `1-100` because `9` is the current minimum port number

Here is my code:

```
 my @ranges;
 push @ranges, '1-65535';

 my $bFound = 0;
 do {
  $bFound = 0;
  foreach my $ptrExclusion (@exclusions) {
   my %exclusion = %{$ptrExclusion};
   print STDERR "handling exclusion @ 7964: ".Dumper(\%exclusion);
   my $currentPos = 0;
   foreach my $range (@ranges) {
    $currentPos++;

    if ($range =~ /([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/) {
     my $firstPortInRange = $1;
     my $secondPortInRange = $2;

     if ($secondPortInRange == $exclusion{first} and
         $exclusion{second} == $exclusion{first}) {
      $bFound = 1;
      my @newranges;
      if ($exclusion{first} - 1 > 0) {
       push @newranges, "$firstPortInRange-".(sprintf("%d", $exclusion{first} - 1));
      } else { # Handle port "1"
       ### Don't put anything, we are excluded from adding this
      }

      if ($currentPos > 1) {
       unshift @newranges, $ranges[1..($currentPos-1)];
      }

      if ($currentPos + 1 < scalar(@ranges)) {
       push @newranges, $ranges[($currentPos+1) .. scalar(@ranges)];
      }

      print STDERR "newranges @ 7985: ".Dumper(\@newranges);
      @ranges = @newranges;
      last;
     }

     if ($firstPortInRange == $exclusion{first} and
         $exclusion{second} == $exclusion{first}) {
      $bFound = 1;
      my @newranges;

      if ($exclusion{second} + 1 <= 65535) {
       push @newranges, (sprintf("%d", $exclusion{second} + 1))."-$secondPortInRange";
      } else { # Handle port 65535
       #### Don't put anything, we are excluded from adding this
      }

      if ($currentPos > 1) {
       unshift @newranges, $ranges[1..($currentPos-1)];
      }

      if ($currentPos + 1 < scalar(@ranges)) {
       push @newranges, $ranges[($currentPos+1) .. scalar(@ranges)];
      }

      print STDERR "newranges @ 8005: ".Dumper(\@newranges);
      @ranges = @newranges;
      last;
     }

     if ($firstPortInRange < $exclusion{first} and
         $secondPortInRange > $exclusion{second} # An exclusion is between the ranges we currently have, this doesn't include "hits" on the exact port number, i.e. excluding port 1 and port 65535
        ) {
      print STDERR "exclusion matched @ 8022\n";
      $bFound = 1;
      #printf (STDERR "currentPos @ 7973: %d\n", $currentPos);
      my @newranges;
      push @newranges, "$firstPortInRange-".(sprintf("%d", $exclusion{first} - 1));
      push @newranges, (sprintf("%d", $exclusion{second} + 1))."-$secondPortInRange";
      if ($currentPos > 1) {
       unshift @newranges, $ranges[1..($currentPos-1)];
      }

      if ($currentPos + 1 < scalar(@ranges)) {
       push @newranges, $ranges[($currentPos+1) .. scalar(@ranges)];
      }

      print STDERR "newranges @ 8026: ".Dumper(\@newranges);
      @ranges = @newranges;
      last;
     }

     if ($firstPortInRange >= $exclusion{first} and
         $firstPortInRange < $exclusion{second} and
         $secondPortInRange <= $exclusion{second} and
         $secondPortInRange > $exclusion{first} # An exclusion is holding our range inside it
        ) {
      print STDERR "exclusion matched @ 8045\n";
      $bFound = 1;

      splice(@ranges, $currentPos-1, 1); # -1 as our index starts from 1, while @ranges index starts at 0
      print STDERR "ranges @ 8051: ".Dumper(\@ranges);

      last;
     }
    }
   }
   if ($bFound) {
    last;
   }
  }
 } while ($bFound);

 print STDERR "ranges @ 7980: ".join(", ", @ranges). "\n";
```

`@exclusions` has hash elements under it with a `first` and `second` values to them which designate port A and port B (lower range and top range) their value can match if the exclusion is for 1 port.

Comment: There is the Number::Range library that will do this for you : http://search.cpan.org/~larrysh/Number-Range-0.10/lib/Number/Range.pm

Comment: @xxfelixxx it doesn't appear to work, maybe its a broken package? ``my $range = Number::Range->new('1..65535'); $range->delrange("250..255"); print $range->range;`` doesn't print what it should

Comment: looks like you found a bug! https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=98623

Comment: doesn't really help :) @xxfelixxx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of modules for working with sets that will make your life easier. I would recommend [Set::IntSpan::Fast](https://metacpan.org/pod/Set::IntSpan::Fast):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Set::IntSpan::Fast;

my $ports = Set::IntSpan::Fast->new('1-65535');
my $exclude = Set::IntSpan::Fast->new('1-2,3-4,4-5,5-6,7-8,9-10,1-100');

say $ports->diff($exclude)->as_string;
```

#### Output

```
101-65535
```

Comment: This code doesn't have the bug include 1-65535 and exclude 1-65535 - which should return empty

Answer (score 3):

The `Range::Object` set of modules is very comprehensive, and [`Range::Object::Serial`](http://metacpan.org/module/Range::Object::Serial) does exactly what you're looking for out of the box

This short program demonstrates

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

use Range::Object::Serial;

my $range = Range::Object::Serial->new('1-65535');
say scalar $range->collapsed;

$range->remove('1-2,3-4,4-5,5-6,7-8,9-10,1-100');
say scalar $range->collapsed;
```

#### output

```
1-65535
101-65535
```

Comment: There seems to be a bug in it, ``my $range = Range::Object::Serial->new('1-65535'); $range->remove('1-65535'); `` should return an empty set, but doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt, without using a library, instead just using an array (since it is not very large).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my @port_range = ( 1, 65535 );
my @ports = map { 1 } ( 0 .. $port_range[1] );
my $exclusions = '1-2,3-4,4-5,5-6,7-8,9-10,1-100';

for my $exclusion ( split /,/, $exclusions ) {
    if ($exclusion =~ m|\-|) {
        # Range
        my ($start, $stop) = split /-/, $exclusion;
        $ports[$_] = 0 for ($start..$stop);
    } else {
        # Single port
        $ports[$exclusion] = 0;
    }
}

my @good_ports = grep { $ports[$_] > 0 } ( $port_range[0] .. $port_range[1] );
my $last_good = 0;
for my $i ( 1 .. $#good_ports ) {
    if ($good_ports[$i] - $good_ports[$i-1] > 1) {
        # gap
        print join '-', $good_ports[$last_good], $good_ports[$i-1] . "\n";
        $last_good = $i;
    }    
}
print join '-', $good_ports[$last_good], $good_ports[$#good_ports] . "\n";
```

**Output**

```
101-65535
```

Answer (score 0):

With a range as small as that you could just keep a list of every port and set flags for which are open & closed, and print out the results.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

# print a list of open ports, given a string of closed ports

my @ports = map { 1 } 1..65535; # start with all ports flagged as open

while (<DATA>) {     # get the string of closed port numbers & ranges
    chomp;
    /\d/ or next;    # ensure we have at least one number to work with

    my @exclusions = split /,/;

    for (@exclusions) {

        # each exclusion is a number, optionally followed
        # by a dash and another number
        /^(\d+)(?:-(\d+))?$/ or next;

        # set the flag to 0 for a single port or a range of ports
        if ($1 and ! $2) {
            $ports[$1-1] = 0;  # single port
        }
        elsif ($1 and $2) {
            @ports[$1-1..$2-1] = map {0} $1..$2; # range of ports
        }
    }
}

# get a list of all ports which are open
my @open_ports = map {$_ + 1} grep {$ports[$_] == 1} 0..$#ports;

# the final list of open port ranges, to be displayed
my @ranges     = ();

# build up the list of open ranges
for (@open_ports) {
    my $one_less = $_ - 1;

    # either add this open port to the previous range,
    #   or start a new range with this port
    #
    (@ranges and $ranges[-1] =~ s/-$one_less$/-$_/) 
       or push @ranges, "$_-$_";
}

# fix single-number ranges for display
for (@ranges) {
    s/^(\d+)-\1$/$1/;
}

# display the result
print join ',', @ranges;

__DATA__
1-2,3-4,4-5,5-6,7-8,9-10,1-100
```

Output:

```
101-65535
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I did this as well, its is VERY slow if your exclusion list is a lot of ports (more than 100)